# How to add "Open with" menuItem to a file

Tags: cocoa

[image]

Refer to this screenshot, i want to add a menuItem "Open With" in my project, i can use codes as below to add menu items programmatically, but is there any way to add the "Open With" easily, or i should draw the sub menu item by myself?

```
 NSMenu *theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];

    [theMenu addItem:[NSMenuItem separatorItem]];
    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Item 1" action:@selector(beep:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:0];
    [theMenu insertItemWithTitle:@"Item 2" action:@selector(beep:) keyEquivalent:@"" atIndex:1];
```

Comment: The `Open With` menu item is added automatically if your app is document based and you have added the appropriate identifiers in Info.plist.

Comment: @vadian, i know, there is a menu in my project by button click, and i want to add the menuItem "open with" to my menu

Comment: Then you have to create everything by yourself.

Comment: @vadian, i find the solution. I can use `LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL` to get the application list for a URL and then create the menu items by myself